# How to trigger mouseover event on stacked SVG elements

Tags: javascript, svg

While the CSS tag pointer-events:none will make an SVG element not be the target of mouse events, only one stacked element can be the target of the event. Is there a simple way to make mouse events target ALL elements that are under the cursor, so that a stacked set of elements will all have their events triggered if the event occurs within their bounding box?

Comment: I can't say this with certainty, but I think there is no easy way to do this.

Comment: I was looking at having the bound event trigger the events for covered elements programmatically in a sort of "chain of command" pattern, but its really a tough problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method on SVGSVGElement (`<svg>`) called [`getIntersectionList()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__getIntersectionList) which will return all elements that intersect with a given rectangle.

As an example, here is a code snippet which will give every SVG shape under the click a random colour.

```js
var  mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");

mysvg.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {

  var  hitRect = mysvg.createSVGRect();
  hitRect.x = evt.clientX;
  hitRect.y = evt.clientY;
  // (leave width & height as 0)
  
  var  elems = mysvg.getIntersectionList(hitRect, null);
  for (i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    // Give each element under the mouse a random fill colour
    elems.item(i).setAttribute('fill', "rgb("+rnd()+","+rnd()+","+rnd()+")");
  }
  
});


function rnd() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 255.99);
}
```

```html
<svg id="mysvg">
  
  <rect width="150" height="100" fill="#393"/>
  <rect x="120" y="20" width="140" height="130" fill="orange"/>
  <rect x="220" y="0" width="80" height="130" fill="red"/>
  
</svg>
```

Unfortunately, this currently only works in Chrome (maybe Safari also?).  Supposedly FF implemented partial support for this, but it currently seems to have been removed.

Comment: It's never been implemented in Firefox.

Comment: Ah yes.  I didn't read the bug properly.  It was only a proposed patch. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=501421

Comment: As usual, chrome is ahead of the game.